# Referencing a class from another project in a RazorPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a ASP .Net Core 3.1 project named "**MyProject.app**", using Razor Pages. This project references another one (in the same solution) that is named "**Utils.lib**". The latter contains this class:

```
namespace Utils.lib
{
    public static class PropertyUtils
    {
        public static void SomeMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now in a "MyProject.app" i have a razor page that is located under:

```
/Pages/Profile/Index.cshtml
```

And i'm trying to reference my util "Utils.lib" class there like this:

```
Utils.lib.PropertyUtils.SomeMethod()
```

But all i get is

> The type or namespace name 'lib' does not exist in the namespace
>   'MyProject.app.Utils' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I tried to add a namespace to _ViewImports.cshtml, with a @using directive but it gives the same error.

At the same time, i can freely use that method in any of my .cs files of the main project, but not in any .cshtml

Also i have this class in main project:

```
namespace MyProject.app.Utils
{
    class SomeOtherUtilClass
    {
    }
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the way i named my namespaces, but i can't figure out what.

What am i missing here? Why can't i reference my classes in RazorPages?

Comment: Does _ViewImports.cshtml contain `@using MyProject.app` ?

Comment: @Anton Yes it does. Tried adding `@using Utils.lib` above or below it but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is my answer. You will be able to reproduce the problem  even in your c# code if you add these `usings`:

```cs
using MyProject.app
using Utils.lib
```

Because `MyProject.app` contains the same namespace, the compiler cannot find your Utils.lib.

You have two ways of solving this problem:

1. Rename namespaces
2. Use in your razor pages full namespace paths like:

```cs
@MyProject.app.Utils.SomeUtilClass
```

or

```cs
@Utils.lib.SomeUtilClass
```

So, you have to remove `@using MyProject.app` from `_ViewImports`

Comment: I've suspected something like that but thought that compiler would at least warn me that i have some ambiguity in my namespaces. Should be more careful in future. Thanks!